# How to send alert using inputted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, alert

I'm trying to create a simple sign in/sign up form that sends an alert to the user once they've hit the submit button. The alert will show the user all the info they have put in (name, email, password). When I run the app the alert comes up as "undefined".

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form>
                    <h2>Sign In</h2>
                    <label>User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit-button si-submit" value="Sign In">
                    <div id="remember"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><span>Remember me</span></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="sign-up">
                <form>
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" id="name" required>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="password" required>
                    <input class="submit-button su-submit" type="submit" id="myButton">
                </form>
```

JS:

```
 var userInfo = document.getElementById("name");
 document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(userInfo.value);
 });
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to be able to have all inputted values show up in the alert box. How can I add more than one value?

Comment: wrap JavaScript in document.onload = function () { <your code> }

Comment: I still only get the first value. this is what I put:

Comment: $(document).onload(function(){

 var siName = document.getElementById("name");
 document.getElementById("mySIButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("You've entered: " + siName.value + " as your name.");
 });

  var siPassword = document.getElementById("siPassword");
 document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("You've entered: " + iPassword.value + " as your password.");
 });

});

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work...

```js
 var userName = document.getElementById("name"), 
      userEmail = document.getElementById("email"),
      userPassword = document.getElementById("password");
 document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(userName.value);
        alert(userEmail.value);
            alert(userPassword.value);
 });
```

```html
            <div class="sign-up">
                <form>
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" id="name" required>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="password" required>
                    <input class="submit-button su-submit" type="submit" id="myButton">
                </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for checking it out! I realized that I'm having issues getting multiple values to pop up in the alert box. Any suggestions?

Comment: u can concatenate the values...  alert(userName.value+ ' '+ userEmail.value +' '+ userPassword.value); or do u want to use multiple alerts? it should work but u will need to press ok so the next one can show

Comment: Yes how do I create multiple alerts?

Comment: not sure why you will want that...but check my answer again...i just added the alerts, one after the other